# Speeding up masks AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently doing the following when applying a mask to a MovieClip:

```
mc1.cacheAsBitmap = true;
_mask.cacheAsBitmap = true;
mc1.mask = _mask;
```

Which works great, however...

mc1 is a complex vector animation, and cacheing it as a bitmap in order to mask it has pretty big memory implications from what I can see, and have read.

Is their another way to implement masks? Or a way to optimise the usual solution?

Thanks

*edit*
Both the mask and mc1 are MovieClips, and they have been added to the stage, the mask is a gradient.
I am using Flash CS6, both movieclip and mask are added to the timeline, where they are being animated

Comment: Applying `cacheAsBitmap` is usually bad for animated MovieClips. See this: http://www.bytearray.org/?p=117

Comment: is the mask rectangular or irregular shaped ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.greensock.com/blitmask/

Quote from the documentation:

> **Can’t I just set the target DisplayObject’s cacheAsBitmap property to true and get the same result? Why use BlitMask?**
>
> *If you set a DisplayObject’s cacheAsBitmap property to true, Flash takes a bitmap capture of that object so that when you move it (only
>   altering the x and/or y properties), the text and vectors don’t need
>   to be re-rasterized again before being rendered to the screen.
>   However, Flash would still need to concern itself with extra pixels on
>   every frame if you’re masking them to only show a small portion of the
>   area. BlitMask, however, only cares about that smaller masked area
>   (after the initial capture of course) which alleviates Flash from
>   having to even think about the extra pixels.*